# Play/Show "swf" in a "a rel="""

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, flash, rel

I have this working code for IMAGES:

```
<a class="showimage" rel="http://www.sitename/images/image.png" >
<span>hover here</span>
</a>
```

plus some javascript and css code.... so the final result is now when you hover on "hover here" it shows the actual IMAGE "http://www.sitename/images/image.png" - something like this ( http://goo.gl/jhyNm )

What I want to ask is, is it possible to show/play .SWF file instead of image.... so the process is the same, I hover on "hover here" text and it shows the .SWF ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but you can try to embed SWF in `div` element and using JS detect `mouse over` event on "hover here" and then show or hide `div`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks I've got it working by embedding object and now when hovering it also PLAYS the swf not only shows it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

About "showing" the `.swf` file - it's pretty easy,
about "playing" it - I don't really know if it's possible just with js.
I guess you'll need some API involved. (an `autoplay` option if exists).

Anyway,html:

```
<a href='#' id='showMovieText'>
Hover Me
<div style='display:none'>
<!--EMBEDED SWF FILE HERE-->
<embed ....>
</div>
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#showMovieText').hover(function(){
 $(this).find("div").css('display','block');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YbWgh/